# App crashes randomly on Android 12 with Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, react-native

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid parent node provided
       at com.facebook.react.animated.InterpolationAnimatedNode.onDetachedFromNode(InterpolationAnimatedNode.java:205)
       at com.facebook.react.animated.AnimatedNode.removeChild(AnimatedNode.java:39)
       at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedNodesManager.disconnectAnimatedNodes(NativeAnimatedNodesManager.java:391)
       at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedModule$17.execute(NativeAnimatedModule.java:806)
       at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedModule$ConcurrentOperationQueue.executeBatch(NativeAnimatedModule.java:173)
       at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedModule$3.execute(NativeAnimatedModule.java:359)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$UIBlockOperation.execute(UIViewOperationQueue.java:579)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$1.run(UIViewOperationQueue.java:915)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.flushPendingBatches(UIViewOperationQueue.java:1026)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.access$2600(UIViewOperationQueue.java:47)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.doFrameGuarded(UIViewOperationQueue.java:1086)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedFrameCallback.doFrame(GuardedFrameCallback.java:29)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:175)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat$FrameCallback$1.doFrame(ChoreographerCompat.java:85)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1103)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:896)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:810)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1090)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7886)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:568)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1045)
```

need some help please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.